# Membership tokens missing after upgrade to civi v5

Tags: civimail, civimember, tokens

I would like to use the membership.fee token in a mail. However, it isn't displayed in the list of tokens the mailer view offers and it's not working when I use it manually. I saw a suggestion to use a membership context, but I'm not sure what that means exactly. I've tried "Find members", saving the list of contacts to a dynamic group and selecting them as recipients, but this won't work either.

I'm running civicrm 5.18.0

Comment: have you considered Scheduled Reminders based on Membership entity - may get around the problem

Answer (score 1):

You may find this provides the missing feature you need

https://civicrm.org/extensions/nzcofuzioncivitoken

Comment: Ah cool. I see you get around the issue of multiple memberships by only using "latest".

Comment: We've tried this, but it doesn't seem to provide up to date data. Plus, we have members with multiple memberships which would confuse this token.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a "context" thing meaning that when you are emailing, even from "Find Memberships", you are emailing to CONTACTS and so are in the contact context, whereas for example if you do a "Find Memberships" and then from the actions menu choose "Print/Merge Document", you are in MEMBERSHIP context and can choose tokens like Membership Fee.

Comment: So, I cannot use membership tokens in emails anymore?